# Broadcome Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA wireless driver problem

Tags: 12.04

Hi I have a Dell Latitude E6510 computer. I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Now I can't access my WiFi network. Cable network is working. I am new one to Ubuntu.

Details of network as follows.

product: BCM43224 802.11a/b/g/n  BCM4353

```
-pc:~$ sudo lshw -C network

PCI (sysfs)  
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82577LM Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 05
       serial: 00:26:b9:cb:d0:a2
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=2.1.4-k duplex=full firmware=0.12-1 ip=139.78.127.227 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:40 memory:f6900000-f691ffff memory:f6980000-f6980fff ioport:7040(size=32)
  *-network
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM43224 802.11a/b/g/n
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=bcma-pci-bridge latency=0
       resources: irq:17 memory:f4100000-f4103fff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 3
       logical name: wlan0
       serial: f0:7b:cb:7f:f7:32
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=brcmsmac driverversion=3.8.0-29-generic firmware=N/A link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
```

Please help me to resolve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code will do it for you

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

darent is corect

Answer (score 1):

Try installing:

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

Comment: Still its not working. Now it shows the wifi connections. when i am used my user account and password. its asked CA certificate. If i selected get option still its re appear